# Convert difference to percentage

Tags: javascript

I am coding in angularJS,  I have got in a situation where the hard disk data is provided to me.
The datas are like:

```
Total: 463.19 MB
Free: 351.60 MB
```

The formula for getting the used space is `total - free` thus in above case,  the result would be `111.59`.

I wonder what could be formula to get output `24.09%` instead of `111.59` ?

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: (Total-Free)/Total*100

Comment: 111.59/463.19*100=24.09

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ thanks for helping me. Your suggestion works too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this,

```
var freeSpaceInPercentage = (((totalSpace - freeSpace) / totalSpace) * 100).toFixed(2);
```

Now variable `freeSpaceInPercentage` should be `24.09`

FYI : `.toFixed(2)` : It will round up or down for you depending on the values beyond 2 decimals.

Comment: Works great! Thank you for helping me and for additional information. (cheers)

Answer (score 1):

**Simply do `(total - free) * 100 / total`**. `Total - free` is the amount left, and the amount left over the `total` is the fraction left. To get percentage, multiply by `100`.

If you want to round to the nearest percent, you can use the `Math.round` method. Then, you could have `Math.round((total - free) * 100 / total);`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula to find free space in `%`,

```
  (total - used) / total * 100%
= (463.19 - 351.60) / 463.19 * 100%
= 111.59 / 463.19 * 100%
= 24.091%
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. :)